# Create an aging KPI where the target/status changes based on a category in SSAS Tabular

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, kpi

I am trying to create a single KPI for support ticket age, but the status needs to take into consideration the "Status Category".  I am struggling to figure out how I would set a single KPI to have different status indicators.  Below is an explanation of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Status           KPI                                                      0-.30 Days    31-60 Days  61-90 Days  > 90 Days
Vendor Ticket   Green  if all <=90, Red if any > 90                       0             0           0           12
Standard Ticket Green  if all <=30, Yellow if any 31-60, Red if Any > 60                5           0           0
Projects        Green  if all <=60, Yellow if any 61-90, Red if Any > 90  0.3           4           0           0
Waiting on Info Green  if all <=30, Yellow if any 31-60, Red if Any > 60  14            0           0           0
```

So in this list of ticket ages, Vendor Tickets would be red because there are 12 tickets over 90 days, Standard Tickets would be Yellow since there are 5 in the 31-60 Day bucket, but Projects would be Green even though there are 4 tickets in the 31-60 Day bucket and Waiting on Info would be Green.

Comment: I can't write up a full answer, but look at SWITCH with SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Status]).

Answer (score 0):

As @TheRizza mentioned, you can use SWITCH(), but before you may need to add a calculated column to determine the age of each ticket in days, then :

```
VendorTicketKPI = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] > 90)) > 0, "Red",
    "Green"
)

StandardTicketKPI = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] > 60)) > 0, "Red",
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] BETWEEN 31 AND 60)) > 0, "Yellow",
    "Green"
)

ProjectsKPI = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] > 90)) > 0, "Red",
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] BETWEEN 61 AND 90)) > 0, "Yellow",
    "Green"
)

WaitingOnInfoKPI = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] > 60)) > 0, "Red",
    COUNTROWS(FILTER('Tickets', 'Tickets'[TicketAge] BETWEEN 31 AND 60)) > 0, "Yellow",
    "Green"
)
```